# How do I conceal RakuDoc (POD6) contents in vim?

Tags: vim, raku, fold

I would like to use vim's `conceal` command to hide all my POD6.  I've tried

```
syntax match rakuPodPrefix /^=begin/ conceal cchar=>
```

without success.

Alternatively, what is a good `foldexpr` to fold away all the POD6?  My vimscript is not yet up to that task.

Comment: If only we knew what a "POD6" is…

Comment: @romainl https://docs.raku.org/language/pod

Comment: A minimum reproducible example in the question would be better than a link in the comments.

Comment: I removed `[perl-pod]`. Rationale follows. It is true that:  Raku is comparable to Perl;  Raku Dock (aka Pod6) is comparable to Perl POD;  Some folk interested in one are interested in the other;  Some technical skills and knowledge and experience related to POD in vim are comparable to those for Dock in vim. **Nevertheless**, based on my interpretation of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315419/should-perl6-questions-be-tagged-with-the-perl-tag-as-well), both generally, and when narrowed to concealing Dock in vim, led me to be confident I should remove the tag for now.

Comment: @romainl You asked "If only we knew what a "POD6" is…"  I gave you a link with the answer.  What is the problem?

Comment: Thanks raiph . I agree with your reasoning, but I don't have the authority to add a POD6 tag.

I don't see the relationships between POD6 and a Dock in vim.  Really, my question as more about how to use vim's 'conceal' feature.

Comment: @JimBollinger "my question is more about how to use vim's 'conceal' feature." Exactly. "I don't have the authority to add a POD6 tag". Please erase the word POD6 from your mind. It creates the same problem that Raku's old name did -- it leads people to think that what it names is more than superficially similar to Perl's POD. It isn't. "I don't see the relationships between POD6 and a Dock in vim." Not a UI dock. "Dock" is my name for what others have variously named POD6, pod, or RakuDoc, all of which are confusing in various ways. (I now realize that Dock in the context of vim is too. )

Answer (score 1):

```
:setlocal foldmarker==begin,=end<CR>
```

Does the trick.